# alternative for jasperreport in c++

Tags: c++, printing

from a c++ program i need to print a simple label. the label contains a text, an image and a barcode.(in my project the label is more complex, this is just for example)

my customer need a way to customize che label layout.

in the past in java I solve this problem using a report created with jasperreport. my customer customize the report with ireport and then i fill the data  with an hashtable datasource (i never connect to an sql database)

anybody know a way to obtain something like this in java

really sorry for my scholastic english

Answer (score 1):

Offhand, it's a bit hard to say -- most report generators assume some sort of database (SQL or at least accessible via ODBC) as the data source. I'd probably look into some that are free and include source code so you can change the data source (though I've no idea how difficult a modification that will be).

The other problem is that printing anything but plain text is somewhat non-portable; you'll need different code for Linux, Mac/OS or Windows. For Windows, one possibility would be [Report Generator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/ReportGenerator.aspx) from CodeProject.com. If you want something more portable, you could use something like [Xport](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/Xport.aspx) to create XHTML output to be viewed in/printed from a browser (or any number of other programs that understand [X]HTML (there's also a [commercial version](http://www.xportpro.com/)). Of course, you could generate output in any number of other formats that support graphics, such as Postscript/PDF, LaTex, etc. This lets you use portable code to generate the report, but usually requires some non-portable code to invoke a viewer.